# How to Call multiple JS and multiple CSS

Tags: php, javascript

my question is i want to call all my JS file like below example shown.

```
<script src="https://cdn.automd.com/function/combo?t=js&f=settings.js:m,carpicker_plugin.js:m,jquery.backlabel.js:m,modals.js:m,function.js:m,common.js:m,clearfocus.js:m,ubox.js:m,jquery.lightbox_me-2.3.min.js,bubbletip.js:m,buttons.js:m,dropdown_account_switch.js:m&v=3.7.1"></script>
```

Similarly i want to call All CSS files as given in following example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.automd.com/function/combo?t=css&f=screen.css:m,style.css:m,containers.css:m,buttons.css:m,inputs.css:m,login.css:m,autocomplete.css:m,selectjob.css:m,header.css:m,grids.css:m,automated_quotes.css:m&v=3.7.1"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question really how to _combine_ multiple JavaScript files into one, and multiple CSS files into one? If so, please clarify that in your question.

Comment: i want to call Multiple JS file in single page.

Comment: It's not possible to _call_ JavaScript files, but you can _load_ them. If you want to load several files with one request, that's usually referred to as _combining_ them.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP tool [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) can be used to combine (and compress) resources.

Comment: @SSK: If this answer solved your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the check mark to the left so that others can make use of it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include CSS and JS files together in one statement. You can however, combine and minify all your JS files and include the resultant JS file in one request. Similarly, you can combine your CSS files and include it in one request.

---

If you notice the URLs in the script and link tags, you'll see that both requests are served by the script **https://cdn.automd.com/function/combo**, which takes the following GET parameters:

`t` - Type of resource (JS or CSS), i believe they set the cache headers and content type depending on this

`f` - comma separated list of files to fetch, combine and server. Not sure what the `:m` suffix to each file does, i assume its a flag indicating whether the file should be minified or not.

Comment: How this guys combined all JS

Comment: Have put in an explanation in the updated answer. Not sure about the `:m` suffix though.